# Add new table row to jQuery dynamically

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a new row to a table using jQuery (dynamically).  Below is the code I am using.

It's creating the new row, but the columns do not get created.  Does anyone know why?

```
$.each(json['rows'], function(k, v) 
{
    // enable export buttons
    $('.btn-export').show();

    // create new row
    var newRow = $('table tbody tr:last').after('<tr></tr>');

    $('table thead tr th').each(function(index)
    {
        var th      = $(this).text();
        var field   = $(this).attr('data-field');

        newRow.append($('<td data-th="' + th + '">').text('test'))
    });

    newRow.effect("highlight", {color: '#CCB4A5'}, 1000);
});
```

The `json['rows']` object is shown below:

```
Object { location_name: "Barnes", places: 4, voucher155: "129.17", paidbycard: "387.50" }
```

Comment: You never seem to be using the key `k` and value `v` supplied by your `json['rows']` which incidentally you could also write as `json.rows`, so there is no chance of your data actually entering your table.

Comment: Why are there quotes around th? y are you appending td after after closing tr ? log the result variable of your code and see what HTML is it producing ?

Comment: OK, thanks for the `json.rows` object. How do you want that to be shown in your table? As *one* row? And into which columns? (This looks like only *one* row to me, so why the name `json.rows`?)

Comment: @cars10 yes one row please...

Comment: ...`This looks like only one row to me, so why the name json.rows?` - because there can be more than one row returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2. Update:**

```js
var json={rows:[{location_name: "Barnes", places: 4, voucher155: "129.17", paidbycard: "387.50" },
         {location_name: "High Whycombe", places: 2, voucher155: "239.23", paidbycard: "225.50" }]};

$('.addrow').click(function(){
     // enable export buttons
     $('.btn-export').show();
     $.each(json.rows, function(i,row){
       var str='<tr>';
       // to just collect "any" properties into the current tr do:
   //  for (col in row) str+='<td>'+row[col]+'</td>';
       
       // if you want to make sure to get the "right" columns, do
       str+='<td>'+row['location_name']+'</td><td>'
                  +row.places+'</td><td>'
                  +row['voucher155']+'</td><td>'
                  +row.paidbycard+'</td>';
       str+='</tr>';
 
       $(str).appendTo('table').effect("highlight", {color: '#CCB4A5'}, 1000);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button class="addrow">add rows</button><br>
<table><tr><th>location name</th><th>places</th><th>voucher155</th><th>paidbycard</th></tr></table>
```

To illustrate my assumptions a bit more clearly this time I added a second line into your `json.rows` "array of objects".

**3. Update:**

By using `appendTo()` instead of `append()` it becomes very easy to apply your chosen `effect()` to the freshly inserted row(s) of the table.

Comment: Thanks, but this results in an error `TypeError: v.join is not a function`

Comment: Well, yes, that indicates, that one of my assuomtions was not true: `json.rows` is obviously *not* an array of arrays. Maybe you could supply some information on your `json.rows` object, so we can help you in a more directed way?

Comment: I have updated my question with the json['rows'] object.  Thanks.